# Mixing ASP.NET MVC into ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

For some reason my routing is ignoring any attempt to access my MVC pages and simply giving me 404s.  I have a WebForms app set up like the following:

Virtual Directory:  thing

So I usually access my site like so:

- http://localhost/thing/someFile.aspx
- http://localhost/thing/someFolder/anotherFile.aspx

The original stucture of my ASP.NET WebForms app mirrors the file system so I have folders full of .aspx files and I need to be able to use them like that.  For some reason when I try to access a page using the MVC routing such as:

- http://localhost/thing/Home/Index

I just get a 404 error.  I have used ASP.NET MVC on it's own and I know that even if I didn't set up my folders properly, I wouldn't get a 404.  I would get the reasons why the page couldn't be found and hints to where the files should be.  Below is my routing info.  Where am I going wrong?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
       "Default",
        // Route name
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        // Parameter defaults
     );
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you tell me what OS you're running on and whether this site is running under VS.NET Web Dev server or IIS?

Routing in MVC directs a request to a Controller class and then a specific Action method. Do you have a class named HomeController with a method named Index?

Assuming you had a controller that looked this this...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

... then the url you mentioned should work. However, ASP.NET MVC will expect to find any views associated with the Home controller in a folder named Views\Home or Views\Shared under your vdir. In this case, for the Index action, it will expect to find a view named Index.aspx (or .ascx). However, a missing view doesn't usually result in 404 - that's usually caused by the controller not being found, the action method not being found, or on IIS 6 the asp.net pipeline not being in the wildcard settings for the vdir.

**update:**

Are you sure your web.config has the MVC HttpHandler in place (so that MVC is in the ASP.NET pipeline). You should have something like this...

```
<add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

... in your `httpHandlers` section and this...

```
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

... in your 'httpModules' section of web.config.

**update 2:**

Based upon your comments I suspect you've not got the ASP.NET MVC code in the pipeline. You should take your web.config and compare it with one from a freshly created MVC site and look for the missing config items. I've suggested a couple above, but there might be more.

Comment: Windows 7 x64 - II7.5 - Site is running under IIS.

I have the conventions in place.  A controller called HomeController with an Index() method.  I also have a View in Views/Home/ called Index.

Comment: Even if I didn't have the controllers and views in place, I wouldn't get a 404, I would get reasons why the route failed.  This leads me to believe the routing is messed up.

Comment: Do you get any breakpoints being hit? Exceptions in the event viewer?

Comment: You will get a 404 if the controller isn't found or the action method isn't found - that's the default behaviour in ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET doesn't look for physical files until way after the point a 404 might be returned. For some actions a physical .aspx file might not be needed (JSON results for example)

Comment: Breakpoints are being hit within the global.asax.cs and nothing in the event viewer.  I am just getting the IIS 404.

Comment: Did this application start of as a new MVC app, or is it an evolved ASP.NET "classic" app?

Comment: The application started as an ASP.NET WebForms app and ASP.NET MVC is being mixed in.

Comment: I was using Classic .NET AppPool.  I think this is related to my problem but still not 100% sure.

Comment: This is marked as an answer - but its not clear what the answer is! I am having the same problem!